# Fit Gensim LDA into SciKit Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim

I have a gensim LDA model that I am working on and I would like to fit into the sciKit Naive Bayes classifier, similar to sciKit's TfidfTransformer():

```
 lda = ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=self.corpus, num_topics=num_topics)
```

The shape of the TfidfTransformer() is a sparse numpy matrix:

```
<2014x4604 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 117869 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

There have been a few posts on how to take the sciKit Vectorizer and feed it into a gensim model but I want to do the opposite, something like:

```
 classifier = MultinomialNB()
 classifier.fit(lda_model, train_class)
```

How would I go about doing this?  I assume that the matrix from TfidfTransformer.fit_transform() is a matrix of tfidf scores for each word in an array of documents like:

```
  [[.1234, .234, .345], # document 1
  [.098, .987, .876],   # document 2
 [.555, .666, .777]]    # document 3
```

If that's the case, I can just replace every word with it's score and feed that matrix into the classifier. But I can't really tell because there's a lot of stuff going on under the hood that I can't see.

Edit:  I was able to print the first entry of the numpy array, which is itself a numpy array, so I printed the first entry of that and got:

```
 (0, 3911)     0.22756829025
 (0, 3826)     0.161385996776
 (0, 3815)     0.100930582918
 (0, 3627)     0.158255401295
 (0, 3621)     0.194939740341
 (0, 3620)     0.100757250634
 (0, 3527)     0.0734744409855
 (0, 3246)     0.109635312627
```

The column on the left must be tfidf scores but I'm not sure what the right is.  I assume wordids and the document id?

Comment: So just to be clear, you're interested in taking the doc-topic matrix from a gensim LDA model, and want to train a scikit-learn multinomial NB classifier on that? Have you tried messing around with the scikit-learn LDA implementation? [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html#sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation)

Comment: Oh my gosh! I did not realize that scikit had that. Any time I tried searching for LDA and scikit I got linear discriminant analysis but nothing about latent Dirichlet allocation. I'll have to check this out when u get home. Thanks!

Comment: It is new as of version 0.17.0, which just came out this month. Unless you have some explicit dependencies for earlier versions of scikit-learn, upgrading probably wouldn't be a problem. Check out my previous link to the Latent Dirchlet Allocation doc page.

Comment: So it seems the LDA model can be a little volatile.  I've got about 2300 texts and if I run a separate LDA model and feed it into NB, I get a different result every time, sometimes upwards of 4 percentage points.  Any idea why?

Comment: I haven't checked, but I would compare the default parameters between the scikit & gensim implementations. Perhaps they're different?

Comment: My gensim model seems to be performing better than the scikit model.  I printed a set of the top k words for each model and the gensim consistently prints the same set, whereas the scikit one prints a somewhat different set each time.  

As it stands, I'd still like to feed my gensim model into my scikit models.  Any idea on how to do this?